# Model Binding .NET 4.5 webforms dropdownlist error

Tags: asp.net, .net, binding, model, webforms

I have a small webforms applications using .net 4.5 and I'm testing the model binding. I have three models Category, CatergoryItem  and Food.

```
public class  Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

}

public class Food
{
    public Category ProductType { get; set; }
    public CategoryItem Product { get; set; }

    public Food()
    {
        ProductType = new Category();
        Product = new CategoryItem();
    }
}
```

I populated one of the dropdowns with food categories ("Meat", "Vegetables") and the other one using the selected category as the type to populate the dropdown. 
I want to have a form that binds to the Food object and populates this object with the selections from the dropdowns.

here is the mark up

```
    <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <asp:FormView ID="SampleForm" runat="server" ItemType="WebApplication2.Food" DefaultMode="Insert" InsertMethod="AddFood">
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList
                DataTextField="TypeName"
                AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                DataValueField="Id"
                AutoPostBack="True"
                runat="server"
                ID="Types"
                ItemType="WebApplication2.Category"
                SelectMethod="GetProductTypes"
                SelectedValue="<%# BindItem.ProductType.Id %>">

                <asp:ListItem Text="Select ProductType" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList
                DataTextField="Name"
                DataValueField="Id"

                AutoPostBack="True"
                runat="server"
                ID="Products"
                ItemType="WebApplication2.CategoryItem"
                SelectMethod="GetProducts"
                SelectedValue="<%# BindItem.Product.Id %>"
                >
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert"/>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate></EditItemTemplate>

    </asp:FormView>
</asp:Content>
```

and here is the code behind

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public IEnumerable<Category> GetProductTypes()
    {
        var list = new List<Category>();

        list.Add(new Category() { Id = 2, TypeName = "Meat" });
        list.Add(new Category() { Id = 1, TypeName = "Vegetables" });

        return list;
    }

    public IEnumerable<CategoryItem> GetProducts([Control("Types")] int?                 productTypeId)
    {
        var list = new List<CategoryItem>();

        list.Add(new CategoryItem(){Id = 0, Name = "Select Food"});

        if (!productTypeId.HasValue)
        {
            return list;
        }

        if (productTypeId == 2)
        {
            list.Add(new CategoryItem(){Id = 3,Name = "Beef"});
            list.Add(new CategoryItem(){Id = 4,Name = "Fish"});
        }
        else if (productTypeId == 1)
        {
            list.Add(new CategoryItem() { Id = 5, Name = "Carrot" });
            list.Add(new CategoryItem() { Id = 7, Name = "Potato" });
        }

        return list;
    }

    public void AddFood(Food food)
    {
        TryUpdateModel(food);

    }

}
```

I managed to get the dropdowns to populate and refresh when the category changes. I want to update the model with the selected items from the dropdown boxes. I managed to get the Category populated, but when trying to bind the categoryitem I get the following error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Source Error:

```
Line 18:                 <asp:ListItem Text="Select ProductType" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
Line 19:             </asp:DropDownList>
Line 20:             <asp:DropDownList
Line 21:                 DataTextField="Name"
Line 22:                 DataValueField="Id"

Source File: c:\Users\Nemo\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Default.aspx    Line: 20 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.]
   System.Web.UI.Page.GetDataItem() +3038873
   ASP.default_aspx.__DataBinding__control9(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Nemo\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Default.aspx:20
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +84
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +20
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +114
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +23
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +88
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4775
```

if I remove the "SelectedValue" binding from the second dropdown, it works but I dont get that data bound to the Food object when inserted.

How do I get my "Food" object populated with data from both dropdowns, and have one of the dropdowns be filtered by the other?